# helm chart to accept both Mi and Gi values

Tags: kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

I have a helm chart and values file.

```
part of helm chart:
    - name: RAM
      value: "{{ .Values.resources.requests.memory | trimSuffix "Mi" }}"
```

here, how can i make it such that if I have values in Mi or Gi, both should get stripped. Also, if its Gi, appropriately convert that Gi(meaning GB's) .. multiply the value by 1000.

Comment: Helm doesn't have any built-in support for parsing Kubernetes resource units.  You can look for a `Mi` string suffix, but in the general case this is a tricky problem to solve in Helm.  Can the program figure out its own memory limits, maybe by looking at the Linux cgroups subsystem, without an explicit environment-variable setting?

Comment: So, alternative is to use %cpu. i think, that is easier than this? what do you say @DavidMaze